# Xamarin.Forms application with AppThemeBinding is not installed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with theme binding. I'm creating application and test it on two phones:

1. Xiaomi Redmi Note 7, Android version 10, system theme - black
2. Xiaomi Redmi 4X, Android version 7.1.2, system theme - white

When I set colors like this:

`<Button BackgroundColor="#000"`

there is no problem, only colors on Redmi Note 7 are not the same as on 4X because of theme.
But when I set colors like this:

```
<Button BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#000, Dark=#fff}"
```

I have problem. On Redmi 4X all works fine, but on Redmi Note 7 application not installed, just freez. Without AppThemeBinding all works good.

In my progect I use:

-Minimum android version: 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)

-Target android version: 10.0 (API Level 29 - Q)

When I run app on Redmi 4X there is no errors/warnings.
I use Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.8.3.

.NET Framework Version 4.8.03761

I have installed SDK Android 9.0 - Pie, Android 10.0 - Q

So maybe you know what problem is.

Also tested on Honor 9S, Android version 10, system theme - black; all work fine, application installed. Maybe problem only in one phone.

Answer (score 0):

The following requirements must be met for Xamarin.Forms to respond to a system theme change:

Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.967 or greater.
iOS 13 or greater.
Android 10 (API 29) or greater.
UWP build 14393 or greater.
macOS 10.14 or greater.

Comment: It works with android version: 5.0 or greater, but don't work only with that phone